# Use a Desktop as a Phone

Tags: android, phone

I am wondering if there is anything that would allow me to add WAN capabilities to my desktop computer.  I have a couple of things in mind.

1) A box that connects via USB, which you can insert a SIM card into.  The box has all the appropriate radios for text and talk.  Additional fees occur.

2) A piece of software that allows me to connect my Android phone to my computer via USB, then use USB to talk and text over the phone.

The difference to most solutions I've seen is that this solution would allow the talk and text to go out over phone lines, as opposed to WiFi, which is much more common.

Any ideas?

[EDIT] I am aware of things such as Skype, but again, I would prefer to not use VOIP.

Comment: Replace USB by Bluetooth and you could get what you want. However, these features have drastically lost popularity. There are desktop phones which integrate mobile phones voice-wise (using the BT profiles which are intended for car environment integration). For text, that was possible with Palm handhelds fifteen years ago. I'm pretty sure it could still work today but good luck finding software which supports it -- outside of cars, that is, again. Maybe the desktop phones also do the trick. But pure software? Unavailable as far as I know. And I have no idea why.

Comment: Google Fixed Cellular Terminals.   (I am unclear of how you intend to use the computer for voice calls, but you do get Fixed Cellular Terminals which can send SMS and data over USB and also a regular phone [ you can also couple it to an FXS card in your computer to do do voice ] )

Comment: If its only for data and SIP, you can use a USB mobile dongle and send it ATA commands over a terminal (and set up a PPP session for data).

Comment: How do you intend to use "VOICE" from your computer?  If you are trying to do something IVR/PABX like, have you looked at Asterisk and X100P cards ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the USB cable.

You can use an app like [Mighty Text](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.texty.sms) to sent text via your phone via your computer.

Or for text and voice you can try something like [Remote Phone Call](https://www.justremotephone.com/)

Comment: Remote Phone Call looks great!  Thanks a bunch!